# Getting ObjectID of mongodb elements from HTML template in django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-forms, django-templates

I am using Python + MongoDB (MongoEngine) for a simple reservation based application.

The application has two models : Restaurants and Reservations.

```
class Restaurant(Document):
    name = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    location = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)

class Reservation(Document):
    restaurant_id = ReferenceField(Restaurant, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)
    time = IntField(min_value=1, required = True)
    number_of_people = IntField(min_value=1, required = True)
```

Reservations has a ReferenceField to Restaurants. [MongoEngine using DBRef internally]

Now, when I render the list of restaurants, I have to give an option of reservation corresponding to each restaurant. In the Django template served corresponding to List of Restaurants, I have included all the three field of restaurant element: restaurant.id restaurant.name and restaurant.location.

Following is the template corresponding to restaurant list.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for restaurant in restaurant_list %}
    <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <h4>{{ restaurant.name }}</h4>
        <h4>{{ restaurant.location }}</h4>
        <a href="{{ restaurant.get_reserve_url }}" class="btn btn-small">Reserve Table</a> 
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

`{% endblock %}

Now if a user clicks on reserve, I need to create a form (using CreateView and forms.Forms of Django).

But the problem is that to save the form data (i.e. an entry in the Reservation collection of MongoDB), I need the reference object of the restaurant. How can I get that ?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used MongoDB for some time, but I believe your question has nothing to do with MongoDB, so I will answer on how you can get a reference to one record (restaurant) when creating another (reservation).

You are not showing what `{{ restaurant.get_reserve_url }}` is, but in general, you have three options:

1.- You add a field to the form to have the user enter the restaurant (via dropdown or auto-complete), but I usually a bad UX.

2.- You pass the reference to the restaurant as a URL argument:

```
/reservation/add/?restaurant=abc
```

3.- You pass the reference to the restaurant as part of the URL:

```
/restaurant/abc/reservation/add/
```

With either 2 or 3, your CreateView will have to extract the restaurant ID from the URL and get the reference to set it as a hidden value on the form.

Here is an example for how to get it from the argument (2) but it is almost the same for (3) only you get the restaurant id from the kwargs instead of request.GET:

```
class ResevationCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Reservation
    form_class = ReservationForm
    template_name = 'form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        restaurant_id = form.cleaned_data.get('restaurant_id')

        # ... Use restaurant to create new reservation

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())

    def get_form_kwargs( self ):
        kwargs = super(ResrvationCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        if 'restaurant' in self.request.GET:
            restaurant_id = self.request.GET['restaurant']
            kwargs['restaurant'] = however_you_get_a_restaurant_obj(restaurant_id)
        else:
            kwargs['restaurant'] = None

        return kwargs
```

and your form will be something like

```
class ReservationForm(forms.Form):
    restaurant_id = forms.IntegerField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    time = ...
    number_of_people = ...

    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = [...]

    def __init__(self, restaurant, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReservationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if restaurant:
            self.initial['restaurant_id'] = restaurant.id
```

Hope this is what you needed. Let me know if I missed your point completely